# Clear the screen and show a banner

Tags: utilities, ncurses

I need a text banner on a screen which is projected all the time. The screen is connected to a PC with tmux on it.

Example of text "banners":

```
figlet $(fortune)
```

or

```
toilet "$(cowsay $(fortune))"
```

You get the idea.

Initially we thought this banner would need "regeneration capabilities" in case something went wrong, so we did something like this:

```
watch --interval 1 --no-title echo Paranoid about crashes, but I should not be
```

but the thing never crashed in a year! (`uptime` > 1yr)

So we are simplifying and deploying somewhere else too. I just want a UNIX command that does the following:

- clear the screen (like `clear`)
- shows a formatted string (like `printf`)
- is modal (like an `ncurses` app)

I started to write something like this, pinched off of a web tutorial:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  char* greeting = "Hello, world!";
  initscr();
  addstr(greeting);
  refresh();
  getch();
  endwin();
  return 0;
}
```

but this is not "modal" (with modal being: disregard all input until CTRL+C) and I may be "rewriting an existing tool".

Which UNIX tool would you use in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command to watch for Ctrl+C (the INT signal) is [`trap`](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html).

```
#!bin/bash

MSG="Hello, world!"
trap "clear; echo -e $MSG" SIGINT SIGTERM

while :
do
    sleep 60
done
```

**Update - Other signals that can be caught with trap**

`SIGINT`  - Ctrl-c 
`SIGQUIT` - Ctrl-\ (this will quit the program, but commands in trap will still be executed)

`SIGSTOP` (Ctrl-z) doesn't seem to be caught by trap.

`trap` can also catch signals issued by `kill`, but I'm not sure how many of them can be caught.

`trap` also supports some other special names:-
`EXIT`, `DEBUG`, `RETURN` and `ERR`. 
Further documentation on these can be found in the [bash reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-trap).

Comment: Simple. Elegant. Trapping SIGINT is golden. Thank you! You could add a link to a list of signals to make your answer even more useful to others stumbling on it...

Comment: I had a hunt through some man pages on my Linux box (signal, 7 signal, kill, posix, etc.), but couldn't find any info on keyboard-shortcut to signal mappings. I know a couple though; I'll add them to the answer..

Comment: Good man... and thorough! (cit.)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you want an infinite loop:

```
while :; do
  sleep 1
  clear
  # the command: echo, toilet, etc.
done
```

Maybe, the problem with watch is that the shell expansion of `$(command ..)` is done once before watch is called so output doesn't change ; change double quotes to single quotes

```
watch --interval 1 'cowsay $(fortune)'
```